# How do I disable irqbalance?

Tags: 10.04, upstart

The title says it all really. I don't want to just kill something that seems so close to the bare metal, and `sudo service irqbalance stop` says `stop: Unknown instance:` -- what am I missing? Should I be disabling it somewhere and rebooting?

Comment: Just curious, what's the purpose of enabling/disabling this? It would seem one would _want_ this enabled...

Comment: I'll be honest, after 3.5 years or so, I can't remember. Presumably it was causing me a problem at the time -- a buggy interaction with something else, in 10.04 or 10.10, maybe?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

And 30 seconds later I found my answer - set `ENABLED=0` in `/etc/default/irqbalance`

Sorry, nothing to see here, move along.

Answer (score 1):

Just a warning that the `ENABLED=0` setting in `/etc/default/irqbalance` setting will not work on recent versions of `irqbalance` (1.1+), it has been [removed](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/irqbalance/commit/?id=bc9cc94b0b451aed1f02e4e1d11d365a8719b05c) a while ago.

As far as I can tell from the source code, there is no way to disable a more recent version of `irqbalance` without actually stopping the process itself. For example if you run a `systemd`-based distribution, this would be something like `systemctl stop irqbalance.service`.

Comment: So we stop the service and then....... use `IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPUS` to control which cpus IRQs are ran on?

Answer (score 0):

In 2018 the reason for removing it completely is a warning from the excellent `cpufreq` Gnome panel applet for managing your processor governor settings, even down to temporarily disabling cores to reduce power consumption provided you have removed `irqbalance`.

https://github.com/konkor/cpufreq/issues/48